# Why do tabs automatically refresh in Safari 5.1?

Tags: macos, safari

My safari (Safari Version 5.1) is automatically refreshing, it's really frustrating.

Any idea why this might be happening ? How can this be solved?

Comment: Both on your Mac *and* iOS devices? By the way, this is off topic if you're not asking about Safari development.

Comment: Oh sorry, the edit has been made.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure why this happens. But I found [this](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1306794) in a forum:

> This issue occurs when the IOS is running low on RAM memory, and cannot store the entire page in the cache. 
>   On Mac OS X, that is a feature to Safari 5.1. Web pages auto-refresh if they are left inactive for a period of time. It can be indirectly disabled in debug menu. 
>   Close Safari, launch Terminal, input “defaults write com.apple.Safari IncludeInternalDebugMenu 1”. This will enable Safari debug menu.
>   Then open Safari, and you will notice a new menu “Debug” appeared beside the “Help”. Deselect the option “Use Multi-process Windows” in the “Debug” menu.
>   Reopen the Safari, you will notice Safari is in single process mode and marked as “SP”. This will prevent the automatic refreshing of webpages.
>   But there is the downside for this method. Many plugins and extensions will not work. So it is up to you. Or you can use Chrome or Firefox.

Comment: Thans for your reply, but i am using a number of plugins and extensions so i think this method is not suitable in this case !

Comment: I was going crazy too until i found one line in css that was causing this issue for me: -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased; (in safari for windows)